# GraalVM Native Image and Log4j causing error: "Defining hidden classes at runtime is not supported"

Tags: java, log4j, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am using native-image to compile a JAR into a windows executable, and the application uses Log4j (v2.19.0) as a logger. Native-image is able to compile the executable without errors, but when I run the program, it gives the following error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to load services for service class org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.Provider
 java.lang.InternalError: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Defining hidden classes at runtime is not supported.
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.generateInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:485)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:387)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:322)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:341)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil.loadClassloaderServices(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:93)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil.loadServices(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:74)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ServiceLoaderUtil.loadServices(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:68)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.<init>(ProviderUtil.java:67)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.lazyInit(ProviderUtil.java:145)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.hasProviders(ProviderUtil.java:129)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:90)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:55)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at com.mojang.logging.LogUtils.getLogger(LogUtils.java:62)
        at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:42)
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Defining hidden classes at runtime is not supported.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:92)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(ClassLoader.java:338)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2382)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassDefiner.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:2448)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassDefiner.defineClassAsLookup(MethodHandles.java:2429)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineHiddenClass(MethodHandles.java:2135)
        at java.base@20.0.1/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.generateInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:479)
        ... 17 more
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

Following this, a segfault occurs and gives this: [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/dxyJeRbV)

I would first like to figure out if there is a possible way to fix the error from occurring at all, but I suspect this might not be possible given the nature of native-image with hidden classes and lambdas at runtime. If that is not possible, then I would like to figure out if there is a way to prevent the segfault from occurring, since it seems to try to fallback to a SimpleLogger right before, which I would be fine with happening.

**What I have tried:**

- Using `-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir` to generate configuration for native-image (before doing this, it did not compile at all)
- Using an earlier version of GraalVM that matched the JAR version (JAR is Java 17; Originally used GraalVM 20.0.1, then tried 17.0.7)

**Restriction**

I do not have access to the source code, only the compiled JAR, meaning changing the version of Log4j would be questionable if not impossible. Ideally there would be some sort of change to my native-image build process, or an argument at runtime that allows the program to run, since I cannot change the source code.

Comment: This is a known issue: [LOG4J2-2649](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2649)